# Getting socket hang up error while running appium scripts using windows OS

Tags: android, mobile, appium, appium-android

I get this error intermittently while running my appium scripts in real device. every alternate execution fails for the below error. Please let me know if anybody has faced this issue earlier and how you have fixed it?

device used: Oppo A7 - VERSION 8.1.0
OS: Windows 10
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up

```
and the execption thrown is below
Session ID: 3fe1bfe2-acb2-4f2f-9dee-0d4699bbfe75
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:46)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at screenshot.Screenshot.captureScreenshot(Screenshot.java:33)  -> implementation given by me
    at docscantests.DocScanTests.afterMethod(DocScanTests.java:552)  -> implementation given by me
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
```

Comment: In error stack, I am not able to see any line mentioning about socket hang up

Comment: Please try to update to appium server on latest version

Answer (score 3):

**Socket hang up** mostly happens because the system port (8200 by default) is under using after tearing down. 
System port is something different than wd/hub port (like 4723). 
Each UiAutomator clients use system port to talk with JWP.

Cases:

1- When you use several appium-based softwares together. Such as Katalon, Appium Studio and Appium itself at the same time

2- When have parallel running or fast running test iterations rapidly after each tearing down

**How to resolve:**

Change the systemPort desired capability of the appium. (ex. change from 8200 to 8210)

Answer (score 3):

Rebooting the device helped me, not just closing it and opening again, but selecting "Cold boot Now" option in Vertual Device Manager for Android studio.

Comment: This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just relaunched the phone and the issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

**Socket hang-up** mostly happens because of the system port 8200, which is a default port. When we run our scripts/ tests every time it'll point to the system port 8200 and when we are executing multiple tests, we will get a socket hang-up issue because after each test appium will teardown or kill the system port. When the teardown is happening and if the next test starts, we will get a socket hang-up issue until the port is available for the execution.

**Steps to overcome socket hang-up issue**:

In your script, set the desired capability key as "appium:systemPort" and the value for this capability should be passed dynamically. Create a collection and keep some 5-10 different port numbers in the collection and for each test, it should pick a value from the collection and send it in sequential order. So this way we can avoid socket hang-up issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error intermittently, and based on the other answer I looked into what was happening with setup and teardown for the tests.

I realised I was creating a new driver for each test I was running, meaning each test created and then destroyed the full driver object. My issue actually started when I used the udid capability to specify the tablet serial number; my assumption is this made the driver creation take longer or somehow be slightly less reliable.

In addition, the actual tests themselves ran very quickly. That then meant I was running into case 2 in the other answer here.

My fix was to move the driver creation to a one-off, using the @BeforeClass jUnit annotation, so that it wouldn't be re-created in between each test.

Answer (score 0):

I have run following command in terminal and It worked for me, Try it out.

adb shell am instrument -w -e debug false io.appium.espressoserver.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Answer (score -4):

i switch on 'ed my system the next day morning and everything worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).